# Why isn't file_put_contents creating a page?

Tags: php

I'm working on a bit of code to generate some random URLs for the pages on my website. My intent is to have the person redirected to the page that they have just created after creating it, but they are instead forwarded to 'switch', a php code that works to determine which function to fire based on which radio button is pressed. Here is my page that allows them to 'upload' to my site:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <title> 
    Learning Made Easy
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php include_once 'googleanalytics.php'; ?>

<a href="http://terrythetutor.com">
    <div class="banner"> </div>
</a>

<?php include 'menu.php'; ?>

<div class="content">
</br>
</br>
</br>
    <form action="../scripts/switch.php" method="post">
    Title: 
    </br><input type="text" name="Title">
</br>
</br>
</br>
    Summary of the video (including questions used in the video): 
    </br><textarea name="Summary" COLS=60 ROWS=10></textarea>
</br>
</br>
</br>
    URL of the video (Yes, this means you need to upload it to an external website.): 
    </br><input type="text" name="URL">
    </br>
    </br>
    Which course does your video pertain to?</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="intermediate"> Intermediate and below</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="college"> College Algebra</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="precalculus"> PreCalculus</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="trigonometry"> Trigonometry</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="calculus I"> Calculus I</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="calculus II"> Calculus II</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="calculus III"> Calculus III</br>
    <input type="radio" name="course" value="differential equations"> Differential Equations</br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit, foo!">
    </form>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<p>
Please understand that you will not be able to change the title, summary, or URL of your video after submission.
</p>


</div>

<div class="footer">
    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

That bit works nicely. After that, they are redirected to a 'switch.php'. You already know what that does.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'intermediate') {
        include('storeintermediate.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'college') {
         include('step2a.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'precalculus') {
        include('replace.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'trigonometry') {
        include('replace.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'calculus I') {
        include('replace.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'calculus II') {
        include('replace.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'calculus III') {
        include('replace.php');
    } elseif (isset($_POST['course']) && $_POST['course'] == 'differential equations') {
        include('replace.php');
      }
 ?>
```

From there, we go to storeintermediate.php, where I have the functionality of grabbing all of the variables, storing them in a database, creating a new randomly generated page with a template format, and extract the URL of the video that they are uploading.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("*******","******","************","*");
$IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$IP = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $IP);
$Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[Title]);
$Summary = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[Summary]);
$URL = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[URL]);


$number = mt_rand(100,99999999); // see $new_url

$nospace = str_replace(' ', '_', $Title); // to enable URL friendly titles

$new_url = $number . $nospace ;  // to ensure that each URL is unique

$data = include( '../template.php');

$embed_URL = substr( $URL, -11);

file_put_contents("../videos/" . $new_url, $data, FILE_APPEND) ;


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql="INSERT INTO `Intermediate Algebra` (Title, URL, IP, Summary)
VALUES 
('$Title','$URL','$IP','$Summary')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

header('Location: http://terrythetutor.com/'.$new_url);

?>
```

Now, my issues: when I submit a test page, the page IS created. But the size is 1 byte and the only thing in the file is '1'. I can't fathom why.

Secondly, the page that gets redirected to (that also for some reason holds the submitted content) IS switch.php, but it should indeed be the page created.

Thirdly (and probably related to the second), I keep having an error with my header when I try to redirect to the newly generated page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all very much,

Terry.

Comment: Instead of creating a new file each time either use a framework (which will handle routing and different page URLs without creating additional files) or use a basic `page.php` that will display the contents based on an URL parameter (so your URL will be like `page.php?page=some_page_id`).

Comment: Was going to write exactly what @André said. You don't create pages that way, you store data in a database and load the data that matches the target URL (using a template). Besides that, there's quite a lot wrong with the code you posted (e.g. URL friendly snippet, mixing concerns), so I seriously recommend that you look into one of the existing frameworks out there (e.g. [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/)).

Comment: @nietonfir What is wrong with the code? What is a URL friendly snippet and 'mixing concerns'?

Comment: @André what would be a good way to use a template page, have another page created with the unique data, and have it all come together? From what I see, the 'include' function won't work for importing a template.. so... what?

Comment: @user2666324 You don't "create a page" itm that you create a file. You populate a template with data *on request*. And replacing whitespace with underscore is not enough for creating proper URLs. What about other characters like ?,&,#,…

Answer (score 3):

The return value of `include("../template.php")` isn't what you think it is. `include` doesn't return what the included file *outputs*, it returns what the included file *returns*, or `1` if the file doesn't contain a `return` statement at file scope.

Comment: But then why does the information get displayed on the 'switch.php' page?

Comment: what is a good way to somehow (for lack of a better word) 'include' a template into each new page?

Comment: what is a good way to somehow (for lack of a better word) 'include' a template into each new page?